# ローカル環境でのみ、ログインに成功してもセッションIDが付与されない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, cookie, session, sessionid

**数日前に質問を投稿してから進展があり、当初記述しておりました内容とは論点（原因）が異なる事が分かりましたので、質問文全体を新しく編集し直しました。**

**[他のQ&Aサイト](https://teratail.com/questions/355888)でも質問しておりますが、回答が中々付かなかった為こちらでも質問させて頂きました。進捗が有りました際には両方にてアップデートしていきたいと考えております。**

#### 背景

コードをいじっていないにも関わらず、実装出来ていたログイン機能が使えなくなりました。ログイン画面で正しいメールアドレス・パスワードを入力しても再度ログイン画面にリダイレクトされてしまうと言った状況です。
尚、deviseは使用しておりません。

ログイン周りのコードに問題があるのかとまず考えましたが、ログを辿るとログインが成功した際のコードに分岐されている事が分かりました。

また`Burp Suite`と言う「ブラウザ - サーバー間（ローカルプロキシ）」の通信の記録を観察するツールを使用し調べてみた所、ログイン後にセッションIDがなぜか付与されておらず、結果として`authenticate_user`に引っ掛かりログインが出来なくなっている状況だと分かりました。この原因を突き止め、解決したいです。

更に`ngrok`と言う、`localhost`にhogehoge.ngrok.comで外部からアクセスできるツールを使い、外部からアクセスした場合に違いが生じるかを確認した所、何とこちらではログインに成功しました。その様子を同じように`Burp Suite`で調べた所、こちらではログイン後にセッションIDが付与されている様子が確認出来ました。

つまりローカル環境でログインを試みた際にのみ、なぜかセッションIDが付与されなくなっているようなのです。
直近でコードに関して作業はしておらず、以下の作業をしておりました。

- Gitの導入。
- 作成した「アプリ1」を、Gitを使用しGitHubにプッシュ。
- Sourcetreeを導入し、GitHubにプッシュ出来るよう連携。
- GitHubの内容をSourcetreeでクローン。フォルダ名を「アプリ2」とし、Sourcetree内で連携させたいローカルのワークツリーに指定。

更に前に作業していた事はと言えば、セッションに関して以下の1行加えた事くらいです。
またこの行は現在コメントアウトしておりますが、状況は変わりません。

**application.rb**

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 8.hours
```

これらの作業が済んだ後、上記の問題が発生した次第です。

#### 該当のソースコード

**routes.rb**

```
get "login" => "users#login_form"
post "login" => "users#login"
post "logout" => "users#logout"
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  before_action :set_current_user
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  caches_action :set_current_user, :authenticate_user, :forbid_login_user

  def set_current_user
    @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def authenticate_user
    if @current_user == nil
      flash[:notice] = "You need to log in"
      redirect_to("/login")
    end
  end

  def forbid_login_user
    if @current_user
      flash[:notice] = "You are already logged in"
      redirect_to("/")
    end
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
before_action :authenticate_user, {except: [:new, :create, :login_form, :login]}
before_action :forbid_login_user, {only: [:new, :create, :login_form, :login]}
before_action :ensure_correct_user, {only: [:edit, :update]}
before_action :ensure_correct_user_account, {only: [:setting_password, :update_password, :setting_email, :update_email, :delete_account, :destroy]}
caches_action :index, :show, :follow, :new, :create, :edit, :user_params, :update, :destroy, :login_form, :login, :logout, :likes, :ensure_correct_user, :followings, :followers, :top

def login
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully logged in"
    redirect_to("/")
  else
    @error_message = "Email address or password is incorrect"
    @email = params[:email]
    @password = params[:password]
    render("users/login_form")
  end
end

def login_form
end

def logout
  session[:user_id] = nil
  flash[:notice] = "You have successfully logged out"
  redirect_to("/login")
end
```

ログインに成功した場合は`redirect_to("/")`の様に、トップページに遷移するようにしています。

#### ログ

ログインを試みた際のログです。
`Started GET "/"`とある様に、ソースコード上ログインには成功しているようです。しかしその後`Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected`と怒られ、`"/login"`にリダイレクトされています。

```
Started POST "/login" for ::1 at 2021-08-24 14:44:31 +0900
Processing by UsersController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JBcKtTsdCT0JXgyIfzjKVqi/8KEz4pRmUXB2Kybn8eHcnz7UKXoMsbBRkBCnoUqwnIdi4hUkZ/6oQKFVqMyG/g==", "email"=>"hoge", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
  User Load (35.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'hoge' LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:255
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 422ms (ActiveRecord: 41.9ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2021-08-24 14:44:32 +0900
Processing by UsersController#top as HTML
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)


Started GET "/login" for ::1 at 2021-08-24 14:44:32 +0900
Processing by UsersController#login_form as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9
  Rendering users/login_form.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/login_form.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
  CACHE User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:51
Completed 200 OK in 244ms (Views: 233.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

#### Burp Suitでの表示

`ngrok`を使用し、外部からアクセスしてからログインした際の記録。
左下の「Request」内に`Cookie`が、また右下の「Response」内に`Set-cookie`がそれぞれ表示されています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ローカル環境でログインを試みた際の記録。
左下の「Request」内に`Cookie`が、また右下の「Response」内に`Set-cookie`がそれぞれ出てきません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 試したこと

サーバーの再起動、パソコンの再起動を試しても状況は変わらず、
ブラウザによる違い（Google Chrome, Firefox, Braveで試しました）も関係ありませんでした。

サーバーやセッション関連に原因があるかもしれず、プログラミング関連の質問としてそぐわなくなっておりましたら申し訳ありません。どなたかご助言を頂けますと有難いです。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

ruby 2.6.4p104
RubyGems 3.0.3
Rails 5.2.3
Burp Suite Community Edition 2021.8.2

#### 追記

以下の作業を試みましたが、依然として結果は同じでした。

- `rails s`をする際のポートを3000から3001に変える。
- コマンドにて`bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear`を実行。
- コマンドにて`rails tmp:clear`を実行。
- `users_controller.rb`の`login_form`内にて、以下の様にセッションの履歴を執拗に消す。

```
def login_form
  reset_session
  session[:user_id] = nil
  session.delete(:user_id)
end
```

また外部から私のlocalhostに接続した場合はなぜか上手くいく為、直接localhostに接続した場合との違いを考えてみました。
ローカル環境から直接localhostに接続した場合は、このようにURL横がビックリマークの表示になります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一方で外部から私のlocalhostに接続した場合は鍵マークになっています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ページがSSL化されているかどうかでセッションIDが付与されないなどの違いが出てくるものなのでしょうか…。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/355888) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 有難うございます。質問文の先頭にその旨を記載させて頂きました。
またシェアして頂いたリンクのような考えがありませんでした。今後は数日は回答を待ち、それでも回答が付かなかった際にこの様な対応を取らせて頂こうと思います。

Comment: RoRは詳しくないですが、「SSLとセッションの問題」となるとCookieの属性に[Secure属性](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)がついていてSSLと非SSLでCookieの共有ができない可能性があります。そちらを確認するとどうですか？

Comment: keitaro_soさま　返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。仰る通り、secure: true に関する記述が原因でした。詳細は回答にて記載致しました。有難うございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

無事解決致しました！
config > initializers 内に「session_store.rb」と言うファイルを以前自分で作ってしまったのが原因でした。ファイルにはセッションに関する内容を記述しておりました。

```
app_name = "アプリ名"
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_アプリ名_session", expire_after: 8.hours, secure: true
```

以前セッションについて自分でカスタマイズ出来ないかと考えてたことがあり（セッションはRailsのデフォルトでは1日で切れるようですが、それを8時間に設定したかった）、これを「session_store.rb」と言うファイル内で編集できると知りました。しかしどうやらRails5以降ではこのファイルがデフォルトで生成されないようでしたので、どうやって編集出来るのかを模索していた所、恐らく[こちらの様なページ](https://teratail.com/questions/239249)を参考にし、ファイルを自分で作成したのでした。

勝手にこの作業をしていた事を忘れておりました…。回答者さまが想像できない部分だったと思います。申し訳ありません。

`session_store.rb` は削除し、 `application.rb` にて一旦今回は以下を記述する事に致しました。

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, secure: Rails.env.production?
```

Answer (score 0):

ログを見る限りログインは成功してトップにリダイレクトまではできていて
トップのコントローラ内のコードがまずくてエラーになってるだけに見えます

Processing by UsersController#login
の中ではエラーはなく普通に
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
でおわってます

Processing by UsersController#top
の中でまず

```
before_action :authenticate_user, {except: [:new, :create, :login_form, :login]}
```

の except に top がはいってないので呼ばれます

その中の

```
if @current_user == nil
      flash[:notice] = "You need to log in"
      redirect_to("/login")
end
```

でまた /login に戻されて
以下 redirect の繰り返しになってるんじゃないですか？

> 尚、deviseは使用しておりません。

ということなのでデータベースの保存ロジックがオリジナルなのであれば
ログインが成功してるのに @current_user がなぜ null なのかこれ以上回答側でわかることはありません

```
  def set_current_user
    @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    pp '@current_user = ' + current_user
  end

  def authenticate_user
    pp '@current_user = ' + current_user
    if @current_user == nil
      flash[:notice] = "You need to log in"
      redirect_to("/login")
    end
  end
```

とかデバッグ入れてみればなにかわかるかもですね

ちな質問とは無関係ですが Rails には
@current_user == nil
のかわりに
@current_user.nil?
というメソッドがあります

Comment: 有難うございます。
仰る通り、ソースコード上ログインには成功しているのに、なぜかその後で`@current_user == nil`の判定を受けてリダイレクトしているようなのです。

外部から私のlocalhostに接続した場合はログイン後に問題なくトップページに遷移されるので、コードは間違っていないのかなと思いました。

外部から私のlocalhostに接続した場合と、localhost内で接続した場合の違いを考えてみました。先ほど追記致しましたが、ページがSSL化されているかどうかでセッションIDが付与されないなどの違いが出てくるものなのでしょうか…。しかしlocalhostは通常、URLの横にこの様にビックリマークはありますよね。。

Comment: https://pcl.solima.net/ror5/archives/53 これとか関係ないですか？

Comment: 有難うございます。試してみましたが、それでも動きませんでした。ただ、SSLが関係しているかもしれないと見当を付けました。

ngrokで外部からlocalhostに接続するに当たり、
http(s無し)で試すと、ローカル環境と同じようにログインページにリダイレクトされました（失敗）。
しかしhttps(s有り)で試すとログインは成功しました。

理由はよく分かりませんが、とにかくsが有るか無いかで結果が変わるようです。。